# check occurance of an integer in a string without using any built in php methods

Tags: php, string-matching, isnumeric, typecasting-operator

```
function findIntInStr($str=''){
$str = 'abc123';
for($i=0;!empty($str[$i]);$i++)
    {
        if(is_numeric($str[$i]))
        {   
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; }
```

This question was asked by me in an interview. This was my answer, However the interviewer asked me to check the datatype of character without using any built-in function. How can I do that here?

Comment: Hi, please edit the question to identify the experiments/research you have done and why these didn't help. Please remember that this is not a code-writing service. Thanks.

Comment: Can you use the built-in `strlen()` function? If not, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Loop through all the characters in the string. If it matches `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. return `false`. If you get to the end of the loop, return `true`.

Comment: The whole point of exercises like this is to teach you how to figure out algorithms on your own. Asking for help on SO is defeating the purpose. Programming is a creative process, not just copying things others have done.

Comment: Thankx for your feedback #Barmar.

Comment: I was expecting some intelligent answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function findIntInStr($str=''){
$str = 'abce234';
for($i=0;!empty($str[$i]);$i++)
    {
        if((string)(int)$str[$i] === (string)$str[$i] )
        {   
            return false;
        }

    }

    return true;}
```

Comment: try your code with `findIntInStr('01234')`. I don't think it will yield the expected result ^^

Comment: Yes, you are right, It is not giving the expected result in the case of 0, can you suggest a perfect solution.